# How to convert from a struct to a document with mongo-go-driver

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm trying to use `$push` to put a go struct into a mongo array.  The go documents, which I've simplified for this example, look like this:

```
type Main struct {
   ID       objectid.ObjectID `bson:"_id"`
   Projects []*Project        `bson:"proj"`
}

type Project struct {
   ID    objectid.ObjectID `bson:"_id"`
   Name  string            `bson:"name"`
}
```

What I want to do is `$push` a new `Project` onto the `Main.Projects` array. What I've ended up doing is quite painful, so I'm hoping there is a better way.  See here:

```
// Create the new project struct:
newProj := &Project{
  ID: objectid.New(),
  Name: "foo",
}

// Then marshall bson:
bsbuf, err := bsoncodec.Marshal(newProj)
if err != nil {
    // ...
}

// Next read the bytes into a document:
bsonDoc, err := bson.ReadDocument(bsbuf)
if err != nil {
    // ...
}

// Now create the update document:
upd := bson.NewDocument(
    bson.EC.SubDocument("$push", bson.NewDocument(
        bson.EC.SubDocument("proj", bsonDoc))))

// And perform update as usual
// ... not shown ...
```

Is it really necessary to transcode to a byte buffer, then read into a document?  I was hoping for something like:

```
...
bson.EC.GoStruct("proj", newProj)
...
```

I did try `bson.EC.Interface("proj", newProj)` but that just inserted nulls into the array.  I am curious to know how others are doing this sort of thing.

Comment: I'm not normally one to advocate for something like this, but I just finished a big mongo/go project a few weeks ago. I would highly advise against using the `mongo-go-driver` and instead use [globalsign/mgo](https://github.com/globalsign/mgo) which is a fork of `mgo` that is still being maintained. Even though `mongo-go-driver` is the "official mongo driver for go", it is very undocumented, under developed, a way bigger dependency than it needs to be, and the code looks rushed. Not trying to bash the package, but I would give that package some more time before using it in production code.

Comment: @GeorgeEdwardShawIV - thanks for the tip. The mongo-go-driver has been driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, there is a simpler way to go about this:

```
newProj := &Project{
    ID: objectid.New(),
    Name: "foo",
}

upd := bson.M{
    "$push": bson.M{"proj": newProj},
}
```

I'm using `github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson`

Comment: Agree. I've switched to globalsign/mgo as suggested.